# Make text center in <ul> using jquery tabs

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

I have `<ul>` tag, in that I have couple of `<li>` items. When I added  text to list item. Text is showing left side. I want make it center. I tried different ways to make it. But still showing left side.

```
 <ul>
      <li > <a href="#fragment-5" >
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResources" runat="server" 
 CssClass="custom-tab"  Text="Favorites" 
 OnClientClick="jQuery('#tabs').tabs('select','#fragment-5');">
 </asp:LinkButton>           
            </a>></li>
    </ul>
```

[image]

see above pic. It shows to left of the tab. I want make it center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you treat the `<li>`'s as blocked elements, you should be able to center align. if you are floating them and they are fixed-width, something like this would work:

```
li { display: block; text-align: center; float: left; width: ...px; }
```

better yet, treat them as dynamically sized inline-block elements and use padding to center:

```
li { display: inline-block; padding: 5px 25px 20px; ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

Does [`text-align`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_text-align.asp) not work?

```
li
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here's a basic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QyDvW/).